# Efficient combined in-place adding/removing of rows of a huge 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D NumPy array and it's huge. I have some computer memory, which is not so huge.
A single copy of the array fits snugly in the computer memory. A second copy of this array brings the computer to its knees crying.

Before I can cut up the matrix into smaller, more manageable, chunks I need to add a few rows to it and remove some. Luckily I need to remove more rows than add new ones, so in theory this could all be done in-place. I'm working on a function to accomplish this, but I'm curious to what advice any of you can give me.

The plan so far:

1. Make a list of rows to remove
2. Make a matrix of rows to add
3. Replace rows to remove by the rows to add (one by one, cannot use fancy indexing here?)
4. Move any rows that still need to be removed to the end of the matrix
5. Call `.resize()` on the matrix to resize it in memory

Specially step 4 is hard to implement efficiently.

Code so far:

```
import numpy as np

n_rows = 100
n_columns = 1000000
n_rows_to_drop = 20
n_rows_to_add = 10

# Init huge array
data = np.random.rand(n_rows, n_columns)

# Some rows we drop
to_drop = np.arange(n_rows)
np.random.shuffle(to_drop)
to_drop = to_drop[:n_rows_to_drop]


# Some rows we add
new_data = np.random.rand(n_rows_to_add, n_columns)

# Start replacing rows with new rows
for new_data_idx, to_drop_idx in enumerate(to_drop):
    if new_data_idx >= n_rows_to_add:
        break  # no more new data to add

    # Replace a row to drop with a new row
    data[to_drop_idx] = new_data[new_data_idx]

# These should still be dropped
to_drop = to_drop[n_rows_to_add:]
to_drop.sort()

# Make a list of row indices to keep, last rows first
to_keep = set(range(n_rows)) - set(to_drop)
to_keep = list(to_keep)
to_keep.sort()
to_keep = to_keep[::-1]

# Replace rows to drop with rows at the end of the matrix
for to_drop_idx, to_keep_idx in zip(to_drop, to_keep):
    if to_drop_idx > to_keep_idx:
        # All remaining rows to drop are at the end of the matrix
        break
    data[to_drop_idx] = data[to_keep_idx]

# Resize matrix in memory
data.resize(n_rows - n_rows_to_drop + n_rows_to_add, n_columns)
```

This seems to work, but is there any way to make this more elegant/efficient? Any way to check whether a copy of the huge array is made at some point?

Comment: Just a note: it may not actually be necessary to do this. You may a) be able to keep from reading in the rows you want to drop b) be able to work with the marked array in your later calculations (i.e. after adding replacing the rows, just remember which rows are valid). It's always better to avoid work entirely than to do it quickly. I guess I'm asking how you get your real array in the first place and what do you plan to do with it after this operation.

Comment: The data is a big MEG + EEG recording which will be processed later by an existing package. Before handing the data to said package, some operations need to be done on the data, such as referencing. I was thinking about using a masked array or some other scheme, but the existing package will not be able to deal with it and I don't really want to modify it to suit my particular use case.

Comment: So you are reading the data from file at some point? Can't you just not read the rows that you want to remove?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I would like to take 2 rows, compute the difference, and replace the 2 rows with the resulting row.

Comment: `data.__array_interface__['data']` is tuple.  The 1st element is an integer that points `to the data-area storing the array contents`.  As long as this remains the same the array is using the same data-area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to perform the same as your code but is a little more brief. I'm relatively sure no copies of the big array are made here - the fancy indexing will work with views.

```
import numpy as np

n_rows = 100
n_columns = 100000
n_rows_to_drop = 20
n_rows_to_add = 10

# Init huge array
data = np.random.rand(n_rows, n_columns)

# Some rows we drop
to_drop = np.random.randint(0, n_rows, n_rows_to_drop)
to_drop = np.unique(to_drop)

# Some rows we add
new_data = np.random.rand(n_rows_to_add, n_columns)

# Start replacing rows with new rows
data[to_drop[:n_rows_to_add]] = new_data

# These should still be dropped
to_drop = to_drop[:n_rows_to_add]

# Make a list of row indices to keep, last rows first
to_keep = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(n_rows), to_drop, assume_unique=True)[-n_rows_to_add:]

# Replace rows to drop with rows at the end of the matrix
for to_drop_i, to_keep_i in zip(to_drop, to_keep):
    data[to_drop_i] = data[to_keep_i]

# Resize matrix in memory
data.resize(n_rows - n_rows_to_drop + n_rows_to_add, n_columns)
```

Comment: unfortunately, `data[to_keep]` makes a temporary copy of the data:
your solution: `10 loops, best of 3: 672 ms per loop`
my solution: `10 loops, best of 3: 50.4 ms per loop`

I appreciate the effect through! and the dropping of rows is much nicer this way.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just returning a view?

Comment: I'm sure: `a = np.arange(10); b = a[3:6]; c = a[[3,4,5]]; print np.may_share_memory(a,b); print np.may_share_memory(a,c)`

Comment: See also: http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-01/ for a very nice explanation of these things

Comment: Ah - it's the nonconsecutive indexes. I get it. Looks like this is as good as it gets. At least I contributed a slightly faster way to calculate the indexes. I've updated the code to contain the for loop.

Comment: I wonder if the left hand side of the assignment at "# Start replacing data" also creates a temporary? I suppose that's your real question. Oh, for an interactive graphical numpy profiler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63860/discussion-between-rodin-and-chthonicdaemon).